# How to evaluate this sum 2?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

$\displaystyle\sum_{x+y+z=2014}xy^2z^3$ $\quad , x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$

I think it maybe use combinatorial method.

Comment: What is that 2 after "sum"?

Comment: Where did you get this problem?

Comment: I can imagine a very long solution involving double sigma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution, I think, uses generating functions.

Let $A(t) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x t^x$, $B(t) = \sum_{y=1}^\infty y^2 t^y$, 
$C(t) = \sum_{z=1}^\infty z^3 t^z$.  Then your sum is the coefficient of 
$t^{2014}$ in $A(t) B(t) C(t)$.  Fortunately, $A(t)$, $B(t)$ and $C(t)$ can be 
evaluated in closed form.  Simplify and write using partial fractions to get
a closed form for the series coefficients.

Comment: "Closed form" is a nice understatement... use a computer algebra system for this, you'll need it.